# What does ‘noch’ mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

“Hier ist **noch** das Foto vom Familienfest.”

This is the first line of a fictional e-mail in my workbook. The rest of the e-mail simply details who is who in the photograph.

I don’t understand the meaning or purpose of *noch* in the sentence. None of the definitions I found online seem to fit here. Help please!

Comment: What is your understanding of *noch*? What definitions in which online dictionaries did you find? What do they mean/ what is your understanding from it? please link and quote the relevant part. thanks.

Answer (score 14):

> „Hier ist *noch* das Foto vom Familienfest.“

In this case, *noch* belongs to the synonyme family including *des Weiteren*, *zusätzlich*, *ergänzend*, *überdies*, etc. In English this would be something like *in addition*, *additionally*, *furthermore*, *moreover*, etc. Perhaps the sender forgot to send the photo with the last e-mail and would like to make up for it now.

> None of the definitions I found online seem to fit here.

Well, there are various sources which have a proper definition, for example,

- at [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/noch): meaning [1]
- at [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/noch#d-1-1-3): meaning I.3
- at [DUDEN Online](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/noch_nun_bis_jetzt_viel): meaning 4.a)
- at [Pons](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/noch): meaning I. 1.
- at [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/noch.html): 4<sup>th</sup> line
- at [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=noch): 6<sup>th</sup> entry
- …

Comment: Of course I know this definition, but it didn’t seem right to me in this context, because why would an e-mail start with “here is, in addition, the photo...”? So does the sentence maybe mean “here is another photo of the family party”?

Comment: @user392289 Because the sender forgot to send the photo in the previous e-mail. *Another* would be certainly not correct, because it is *noch das Foto* and not *noch ein Foto*.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: could also mean "still". The photograph does still exist (despite a long time, or has been almost forgotten). Need the context to judge if it's that or furthermore.

Comment: @a_donda, no, the meaning *to still exist* would be expressed with a different word order in the German sentence, namely so that *noch* modifies *hier*, for example, *Noch ist das Foto vom Familienfest hier* or *Das Foto vom Familienfest ist noch hier*. The word order as given in the original sentence does not allow this interpretation, because *noch* comes after *hier*.

Comment: The usage of "noch" in this case can also convey a sense of following up on something which was talked about or mutually agreed upon before. Maybe the two persons here met at the family party and one of them promised to the other to send the photo. In a similar context, "noch" can apply to making a closing remark in a discussion or wrapping up an open issue or topic in general. German singer-songwriter Reinhard Mey has a famous line in his signature song "Gute Nacht, Freunde" : _Was ich noch zu sagen hätte, dauert eine Zigarette und ein letztes Glas im Stehen._

Comment: @kriegaex *"The usage of 'noch' in this case can also convey a sense of following up on something which was talked about or mutually agreed upon before."* That is what my answer indicates.

Comment: Of course it does, which is why I commented under it in order to add some more _Sprachgefühl_-like context in addition to your example with the previously forgotten photo and to add another example to your wonderful academical answer. If I would have disagreed with your answer, I would have said so and maybe even posted another one. But I did not, because I strongly suggest that yours be accepted as the best and correct one. :-)

Comment: @kriegaex Uh, too much of the praise, but thank you very much :-)

Comment: Hmmm... language is so interesting. This usage, which is fairly common ("hier ist noch mein versprochener Beitrag" usw.) does not really mean that anything is *additionally* done or sent; it is rather that a loose thread was wrapped up. A promise made, an obligation yet --"still"! -- pending. The underlying, general meaning of "noch" -- unfinished, continuing -- shines through here. A bit of Duden's 3.d, a missing end point. (So I agree with @kriegaex' first remark but disagree with his complete agreement with you ;-).)

Answer (score 6):

One possible scenario is that the sender has announced before that he would send the photo, and when he actually does send it, he refers to the earlier communication by *noch*. Hence, in this case *noch* is a brief way to say *as mentioned earlier*.

Answer (score 3):

I would interpret "noch" as an additional event late in the time-axis.

I take Inspector Columbo as an example: In the German translation, when he leaves a room and turns around to pose an additional question, he says:

> Eine Frage hätte ich noch.

instead of

> Ich hätte ein Frage.

which would be the right phrase in an ongoing conversation. So maybe in you example the photo is handed over at a time where the conversion is already finished?!

Comment: Would be conceivable in an ongoing conversation, too, if the topic has changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

In this case *noch* most probably refers to a previous conversation not depicted there. I see three possible meanings:

- *as mentioned earlier* (see Martin Peters response)
- a short form of *by the way*, long form would be: "Übrigens, hier ist noch das Foto...", (in the books "by the way" is usually translated to just "übrigens", but colloquially you would use it together with a "noch" in many/most cases)
- it could be referencing eg. a previous e-mail in which the writer of that e-mail forgot to send the photo and now does it with this. I don't know if there is a word for that in english

If it were a "real" e-mail, there would also be the possibility that it's just a colloquial fill word with no meaning, but since it's from a workbook I doubt that

Answer (score 1):

```
“Hier ist noch das Foto vom Familienfest.”
```

In this context it doesn't carry much meaning. If you only said

`Hier ist das Foto vom Familienfest`

this would simply have the meaning of `"Here is the photo of the Family celebration"`.
With the `noch` it could mean that they were just saying goodbye to each other and he/she remembered to give the photo. In this case it would mean `"Oh, here is the photo of the family celebration"` or `"Also, here is the photo of the family celebration"`.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. So you do deny then that there e.g. might have been a conversation earlier where the photo was "promised to show" and in the current e-mail it finally happens? Because your mentioned possibilities when such a sentence could occur seems quite limited to me.

Answer (score 1):

*Noch* is used here as a ["modal particle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_modal_particles)

German makes frequent use of these particles to reflect mood in colloquial, often spoken, registers. They are infamously difficult to translate, as grammatical mood isn't encoded in English in this way.

Literally translated, your example could be: "Here is *yet* a photo from the Family Festival." However, unless you're coming from dutchy Pennsylvania where we sometimes use this particle specifically, the "yet" doesn't lend the same semantic value as it does in German.

Think of it as a means to draw attention to the fact that you're transitioning from one idea to the other, as if to say, "We have been spending a lot of time with family, and we are enjoying it! (In fact,) here is (yet) a photo from the family festival." Without the words in parentheses, the transition between those thoughts is less "smooth," *sozusagen*.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say its another convention, something along the lines of "I attach", but a slightly more colloquial one. As you already have pointed out, it's introducing the photo that has been attached to the email.

Comment: What type of convention do you refer to? Something that is listed anywhere? Where in the question did the OP point out anything as "introducing the photo..." - should your answer rather be a comment than an answer?

Comment: By convention I mean that "noch" is being used quite often in emails as a kind of idiom (or in German, a "Floskel" if that rings a bell) without the original meaning of "additional", and instead as a statement that something is being sent, or attached.

Comment: PLease include your clarification into your answer.